# C++ How to read/split EPRT command?

Tags: c++, server, ftp, client, scanf

I am currently writing a C++ FTP server and I was wondering what would be the best way to read the EPRT command from the client.

```
<< DEBUG INFO. >>: the message from the CLIENT reads: 'EPRT |2|::1|58059|\r\n'                 
                                                             ^   ^   ^                     
                                                    Ip Version   |   |                   
                                                                 |   |                     
                                                    Ipv6 Address-    |               
                                                         Port Number-
```

I tried using the sscanf function in multiple ways but I don't think I'm doing it right.

```
// method one
int ipVersion;
char* portNum;
char* v6_addr;
int scanned_items = sscanf(receive_buffer, "EPRT |%d|%s|%s|", &ipVersion, &v6_addr, 
                                                                         &portNum);
// method two
int ipVersion;
char* portNum;
char v6_addr[3];
int scanned_items = sscanf(receive_buffer, "EPRT |%d|%s:%s:%s|%s|", &ipVersion, 
&v6_addr[0], &v6_addr[1], &v6_addr[2], &portNum);
```

Should I be storing the IP address and port number differently. Any ideas?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
            int ipVersion;
            char ipv6_str[64], rest[47], port[12];
            int scanned_items = sscanf(receive_buffer, "EPRT |%d|%s", &ipVersion, rest);
            char *first = strchr(rest, '|');
            *first = 0;
            scanned_items = sscanf(rest, "%s", ipv6_str);
            char *portT = first + 1;
            char *second = strchr(portT, '|');
            *second = 0;
            scanned_items = sscanf(portT, "%s", port);
```

If anyone was interested

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in a slightly more concise way with just using the sscanf function.

```
int af;
char ip_str[40];
int port = -1;
sscanf(receive_buffer, "EPRT |%d|%[^|]|%d|", &af, ip_str, &port)
```

If you need to convert to a different format you can do so as you see fit.

By checking that the function returns 3 you can make sure it has parsed correctly. Also checking that port does not equal -1 is another easy check.